# show a row from the same table when pin is entered php

Tags: php, mysql

have this code so someone can check the authenticity of their product buy typing their serial number into a box and it will show if the product come from me and that works perfectly fine but my problem is that I'm trying to echo another Column in the same row that the serial number is in so it will also echo a description of the product once the correct serial number is entered, I've tried a few thing but I'm just going around in circles, any help would great, thanks in advance.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pin']))
 {
// include Database connection file 
include("db_connection.php");

$pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pin']);

$query = "SELECT pin,product FROM auth WHERE pin = '$pin'";


if(!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query))
{
    exit(mysqli_error($con));
}

if(mysqli_fetch_array($result) > 0)
{
    // authentic code entered
    echo '<div style="color: green;"> <b>'.$pin.'</b> This is a genuine product </div>';
}
else
{
    // not valid code entered
    echo '<div style="color: red;"> <b>'.$pin.'</b> Your product is not authentic! </div>';
 }
}
 ?>
```

Comment: You need to add the extra column to your query (i.e. `SELECT pin,description FROM auth...`) and then you can use `mysqli_fetch_array($result)` to get the data as an array.

Comment: @Andrew Thanks for your help, is this correct?

Comment: Check my answer below and see if that works for you.

Comment: Ok I will try that now, just seen it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how you can get the extra column and show it in your output. Just add the extra column name to your query and output it where you want. Note that I used `description` for the column name. You might want to rename that to match the real name of the column you want.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['pin']))
{
    // include Database connection file 
    include("db_connection.php");

    $pin = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['pin']);

    $query = "SELECT pin,description FROM auth WHERE pin = '$pin'";


    if(!$result = mysqli_query($con, $query))
    {
        exit(mysqli_error($con));
    }

    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        // authentic code entered
        echo '<div style="color: green;"> <b>'.$pin.'</b> This is a genuine product </div>';

        // get extra column and display
        $data = mysqli_fetch_array($result);
        echo '<div>' . $data['description'] . '</div>';
    }
    else
    {
        // not valid code entered
        echo '<div style="color: red;"> <b>'.$pin.'</b> Your product is not authentic! </div>';
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: @wogwan Cool, glad I could help